# View is not displaying when keyboard is displaying?

Tags: android, keyboard, android-keypad

My app have login screen, it supports landscape and portrait. It is working fine. My problem is that keyboard is displaying when click on edit text in portrait mode is fine. Screen looks like this:

[image: portrait]

But landscape mode does not look like in portrait mode. Screen looks like in landscape mode:

[image: landscape]

This is my manifest code:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.activities"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
    
    <!-- Allow to connect with internet -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/launcher_icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        
        <!--  Add Google Map Library -->
        <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
       
        <activity
            android:name=".SplashActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:noHistory="true" android:theme="@style/generalNoTitle">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".LoginActivity" android:theme="@style/generalNoTitle" android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation" />
        <activity android:name=".MenuActivity" android:theme="@style/generalNoTitle" />
        <activity android:name=".RegularReportsActivity" android:theme="@style/generalNoTitle" android:screenOrientation="landscape"/>
        <activity android:name=".StageMaleAndFemaleActivity" android:theme="@style/generalNoTitle" android:screenOrientation="landscape"/>
        <activity android:name=".MapViewActivity" android:theme="@style/generalNoTitle" android:screenOrientation="landscape"/>
        <activity android:name=".ReportViewActivity" android:theme="@style/generalNoTitle" android:screenOrientation="landscape"/>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

How to display same like portrait mode in landscape mode? also, can any one guide me?

Comment: Is this a custom keyboard ?

Comment: add all your view in scrollview and android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation" add this into your activity tag in manifest this will solve your problem

Comment: @lokoko no default keyboard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add **android:imeOptions="flagNoExtractUi"** for Edit Text

Answer (score 0):

Could you add the following to your manifest file :

```
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"
```

Also add the enclose your login page under a scrollView. Something like

Comment: Did you enclose your layout in a scrollview ?

Comment: ya i have added scrollview

Comment: Try this : 
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"

Comment: Could you share your manifest ? did you try android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation" ? this is supposed to work. Basically when you change the orientation, it recreates and calls the onCreate again. Also, do you have the same layout for both screens ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25152/discussion-between-lokoko-and-chiru)

Answer (score -1):

Surround your layout with a < Scroll View >

add this line in androidmanifest

android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize|adjustPan"

Comment: @chiru,why you need portrait keyboard in landscape mode. By default android OS activates separate keyboard for portrait and landscape mode for user interaction. you will force to change this. it misbehave your app.

Answer (score -1):

I think you did not implement app login screen for landscape mode .So, it is showing default view .

create a sub folder **layout-land** in **res** folder implement UI for landscape also

Comment: What do you mean by implementing it for the landscape mode ?